# OpenApi Generator create models with type String instead of Date

Tags: angular, typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

Im using [OpenApi Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to create services and models for my angular project.

This is an example of my Json:

```
"uploadDate" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "description" : "Data caricamento",
              "format" : "date-time"
            },
```

When I generate the files uploadDate is converted to String instead of Date.

See:

```
     /**
     * Data caricamento
     */
    uploadDate?: string;
```

Is there a way to add a configuration and create models with Date as a type where format is date-time?

This is the script that I use to launch the generation:

```
"generate": "openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-angular -i openapi.json -o ./generated-sources/client"
```

Answer (score 14):

Fixed by adding: **--type-mappings=DateTime=Date**

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the *type mapping*: it lets you use alternative Date libraries.
You either provide this argument to your command:

```
$ openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript \
  --type-mappings=DateTime=Date \
  --config openapi.config.json
```

Or add it to your config JSON:

```js
{
  // ...
  "typeMappings": {
    "DateTime": "Date"
  }
}
```

There is, however, an issue here: your models would say `field: Date`, but they will contain a string. OpenAPI-generator won't construct `Date` objects :(

See issues:

- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/926
- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1875